# Failed to open stream: Permission denied - Artisan

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, file-permissions, laravel-artisan

I'm working on a Laravel project since two days and I never had any problem with my migrations. But this morning, when I try `php artisan migrate --seed`, I have the following error :

```
[ErrorException]
Include(D:\Programmes\xampp\htdocs\Laman): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

So I tried `php artisan cache:clear`, `php artisan config:clear` and `php artisan tinker` and got the exact same error. And when I look into my permission, everything look fine:

```
drwxr-xr-x 1 Foo Bar 197121      0 Apr 26 06:48 app/
-rwxr-xr-x 1 Foo Bar 197121   1646 Apr 25 17:21 artisan*
drwxr-xr-x 1 Foo Bar 197121      0 Apr 25 17:21 bootstrap/
-rw-r--r-- 1 Foo Bar 197121   1378 Apr 25 19:54 composer.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 Foo Bar 197121 123397 Apr 25 19:54 composer.lock
drwxr-xr-x 1 Foo Bar 197121      0 Apr 26 06:32 config/
drwxr-xr-x 1 Foo Bar 197121      0 Apr 25 17:21 database/
drwxr-xr-x 1 Foo Bar 197121      0 Apr 25 23:09 node_modules/
-rw-r--r-- 1 Foo Bar 197121   1075 Apr 25 22:52 package.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 Foo Bar 197121   1055 Apr 25 17:21 phpunit.xml
drwxr-xr-x 1 Foo Bar 197121      0 Apr 26 06:24 public/
-rw-r--r-- 1 Foo Bar 197121   3424 Apr 25 17:21 readme.md
drwxr-xr-x 1 Foo Bar 197121      0 Apr 25 17:21 resources/
drwxr-xr-x 1 Foo Bar 197121      0 Apr 26 06:48 routes/
-rw-r--r-- 1 Foo Bar 197121    563 Apr 25 17:21 server.php
drwxr-xr-x 1 Foo Bar 197121      0 Apr 25 17:21 storage/
drwxr-xr-x 1 Foo Bar 197121      0 Apr 25 17:21 tests/
drwxr-xr-x 1 Foo Bar 197121      0 Apr 25 19:55 vendor/
-rw-r--r-- 1 Foo Bar 197121    505 Apr 25 23:14 webpack.mix.js
```

Comment: php artisan cache:clear from the project directory, then chmod -R 777 app/storage and finally php artisan dump-autoload

Comment: Read my post entierly please

Comment: did you tried this command php artisan dump-autoload

Comment: I can't execute all artisan commands in this project... but I can do npm commands

Comment: Solution found! I had to do composer dump-autoload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
sudo php artisan cache:clear
```

And same for others as well.

Comment: I'm on Windows, so no sudo :/

Comment: @Wizix You need to install Linux Bash for Windows. You can use this: http://win-bash.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Do I really have to use Linux Bash? All my other Laravel projects work well on Windows. (I really love Linux, but I can't install it on this computer and I hate to mix OS)

Comment: Solution: composer dump-autoload :D

Comment: @Wizix Thanks for updating me. :)

Answer (score 3):

Execute from the project directory.

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

And then execute

```
composer dump-autoload
```